# How to get text from div children without id in webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have to make a new project in C# in `visual studio 2017` to get text (bold font in code) in a textbox control, from a html element on webbrowser control and first div to come with dynamic ID (bold font in code) if the id contains a string ("183iT0R0T0R0x0_aria"), including child div without ID. Please check the HTML below.

I tried many ways but no catch the solution until now.

The last code I tried :

```
 var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.All)
        {

            if (element.InnerHtml.Contains("183iT0R0T0R0x0_aria"))
            {

                textBox4.Text = element.Children[0].InnerText;
                break;
            }
```

from this innerhtml :

```html
<div id="Pad9a87f180614e169305e60f1b383ece_1_183iT0R0T0R0x0_aria" style="max-width:44.65mm;position:relative;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;" class="A58b33aac09d744078b91e697d87c7cb2289 cannotGrowTextBoxInTablix cannotShrinkTextBoxInTablix">
  <div style="width:44.65mm;min-width: 44.65mm;">
    <div style="direction:rtl;width:100%;" class="r15"> This TEXT I WANT TO Get IT </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track using `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")`, but then you didn't end up using that `elements` list you just built and instead use `webBrowser1.Document.All`, which will look through *every element* in the document, not just `div` elements.

Also, using `InnerHtml` will give you weird results because you will get a match to any element that has a `div` with the right `id` *inside*, as well as the actual `div` elements you want. So you should do the comparison only on the `id` attribute of the elements.

Maybe something like this:

```
var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
    if (element.Attributes["id"].Contains("183iT0R0T0R0x0_aria"))
    {
        textBox4.Text = element.Children[0].InnerText;
        break;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure `element.Children[0].InnerText` will work. You might need to use `element.Children[0].Children[0].InnerText` if you know there will always be two `div` elements inside.