# C# webbrowser get unknown value string

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a webbrowser in c# windows form to display a web page then pull a string from the website and paste it in a textbox. For example, the web page is a random number generator. Im trying to get the textbox to display that randomly generated number.
I've got the webbrowser1 to display the website just can't figure out how to display that number in the textbox.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877523/how-to-get-text-from-div-children-without-id-in-webbrowser-c-sharp) help?

Comment: Thanks that's the closest thing to what I'm trying to do. will see if that helps